# Избавление от повторяющихся действий при работе со статическими классами

Tags: c#

Добрый день.

На днях столкнулся со следующий проблемой:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    //здесь действия со статическим классом A
}
public void AnotherMethod()
{
    //те же действия, но со статическим классом B
}
public void SomeAnotherMethod()
{
    //опять те же действия, но со статическим классом C
}
```

Я повторяю одни и те же действия только с разными классами, если бы это был обычный класс, я бы создал обобщённый метод и не парился, но классы статические. Может существует способ как-то избавиться от повторямых действий, не избавляясь от статических классов?

Или же как добиться глобальной области видимомости для экземпляров нестатических классов, если это проще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему совсем не вижу. Если я хочу работать со статическими классами в таком виде, я бы сделал так:
Объявил бы в классе App статическое поле объекта и в начале каждого такого метода переключал бы его. Если же что, то можно включить и dynamic для currentObject вот примерно так

```
class App
{
   public static object currentObject;
   //public static dynamic object currentObject;
   public static object classA, classB, classC;

}
class MyClass
{
public void SomeMethod()
 {
   App.CurrentObject = App.classA;
   DoWithCurrentClass();    
 }
public void AnotherMethod()
 {
   App.CurrentObject = App.classB;
   DoWithCurrentClass();
 }
public void SomeAnotherMethod()
 {
   App.CurrentObject = App.classC;
   DoWithCurrentClass();
 }
void DoWithCurrentClass()
 {
  //Действия с CurrentObject
 }
}
```

Comment: да, и правда хорошая идея, спасибо